# No image presented when opening Stackexchange web

Tags: discussion

I'm bothered with the prob for a long time. Everytime I open a stack link, the words can be presented well, but the image never show up (the case in my screenshot). I tried refresh, log in but nothing works. So do you have an idea that there is any way to solve it? Thanks.

[image]

---

And this is always the case (image description blaaa)

[image]

Comment: The image block always shows "enter image description there".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am not sure what a "stack link" is. Is this question TeX related?If so, rather than posting screenshots please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This should be a minimal piece of TeX code that compiles and reproduces your problem.To me at least this question is very unclear so it is likely closed unless you can add a MWE and more information,

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. What I mean by "stack link" is an arbitrary page in stackexchange. It's not Tex related, it's stackexchange,  the web itself related. When I open a stackexchange page, there is no image showing where there is supposed to be an image.

Comment: Why do you post it here? The overall stack meta would have been best? It is off-topic here.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Most images on this site (certainly those uploaded via the buttons in the post editor) are hosted on imgur. I think I heard that imgur is blocked in some countries (see for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341825).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not reproducible and therefore difficult to diagnose. This may be better-suited on [meta.se] with additional details about your browser, country (location) and problem persistence.